# What PHP & Xdebug based Editors do people use other than Eclipse, Netbeans (anything java based) or VIM

Tags: php, debugging, editor, debug

What editor do people here use in Linux?  I want Xdebug support but I don't want something java based (eclipse, netbeans, etc) nor do I really want to use VIM.  Any native GTK based editor/sdk that supports PHP & xdebug would be awesome.

Comment: emacs and geben pop into mind. I am not answering because I don't have personal experience with geben or xdebug. But I am sure a sizable crowd won't leave emacs for the life of it.

Comment: I should mention I basically want step debugging in PHP.  I can do it with netbeans, but netbeans is java based, slow and a memory hog.  I've used VIM but that's a little clunky.  I'm a huge fan of jEdit.  If there was something like this that is a native non java based client that would be awesome as well.

Answer (score 2):

## [Aptana Studio 3](http://aptana.com/products/studio3)

Is by far one of the most comprehensive IDEs I've used for PHP development (or Web development for that part).

[image: go!]

Here's an additional screenshot of it's on-the-fly debugging, autocomplete, and hinting.

[image: example]

Comment: I grabbed a copy of the 3.0 preview release today and tested it on 10.10.  It seems fairly nice, but it's slamming on my CPU for some reason.  As soon as I open it, my CPU usage goes to about half.  It looks like it has a lot of features but does it support step through debugging in PHP?

Comment: @xamox - define "step through" you mean like setting up break points and performing executions?

Comment: Yeah, stopping at break points, and being able to view things like the call stack and variable's, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I recently switched from Netbeans to [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) and haven't looked back. With a zero config setup you can start using xdebug immediately - both for debugging pages, and also for commandline scripts.

You can do all the obvious stuff like breakpoints, and step debugging - but you can also step "in" and step "over" to be able to sensibly handle methods that you don't really care about stepping through. It has the abiltiy to "watch" for variables and values as you step too.

Comment: I no longer do much PHP dev, but thanks for the heads up.  Sadly I never came to a one size fits all.  PhpStorm looks nice, but I'm also an open source maniac and would like my editor to be.  I found geany to actually be a very completely editor except for the fact I can't set break points, it does let me block comment and mass find replace easily so debugging happens pretty quick.

Comment: phpstorm is the best ide used by me as well, unfortunately is not free :( but 90$ is good price if you need it everyday

Answer (score 1):

I use [geany](http://geany.org) for python as well as php. Just love it. See [here](http://www.geany.org/Download/Extras) for snippets and colorschemes. I also created a [tag creator](https://github.com/sagarchalise/My-Scripts/blob/master/geany_tag_creator.py) for geany based on its documentation.

Comment: I tried geany as well, I like it has git support already but doesn't seem to support step debugging with PHP.

Comment: it has a plugin called gdb. Other lightweight editors especially on webfront include `gphpedit` `bluefish` and then there is `quanta ` which is based on KDE but I mostly use geany.

Comment: I should mention, I no longer do PHP dev but python full time now, and I absolutely love geany for python, it has everything, light weight, and cross platform.